# AppleScript For Multiple Safari Tabs And Mouse Click?

Tags: javascript, applescript

Complete noob to AppleScript here with a rather complex one:

I would like automate a script that can do the following:

1. After launching, waits for 61 minutes without doing anything, then:
2. Opens Safari with 16 tabs (and 16 separate URLS)
3. Clicks a “Roll!” button on each of the 16 tabs, then pauses for 10 seconds, then:
4. Closes Safari
5. Waits another 61 minutes, then:
6. Performs 2 through 5 over again for a total of 15 repetitions.

One thing to note:

Each URL is unique to the other 15, but they are the same for every repetition.

Is this even possible? From my research into AppleScript I understand there will need to be a little Javascript in there too?

All help appreciated!!
Cheers

**UPDATE:** Ok, I've been tinkering and I found a script to open the 16 tabs (set to generic URLS at the mo):

```
set urlList to {"http://www.macintouch.com/", "http://www.macnn.com/", "http://www.macworld.com/", "http://www.thinksecret.com/", "http://www.tuaw.com/", "http://www.tuaw.com/", "http://www.tuaw.com/", "http://www.tuaw.com/", "http://www.tuaw.com/", "http://www.tuaw.com/", "http://www.tuaw.com/", "http://www.tuaw.com/", "http://www.tuaw.com/", "http://www.tuaw.com/", "http://www.tuaw.com/", "http://www.tuaw.com/"}
set numURLs to (count urlList)

tell application "Safari"
    activate
    -- create all the tabs that are needed
    tell application "System Events"
        -- enter the url in the open window
        keystroke (item 1 of urlList)
        key code 36
        repeat with i from 2 to (numURLs)
            -- for each additional url, first create a tab
            tell process "Safari"
                click menu item "New Tab" of menu "File" of menu bar 1
            end tell
            -- now enter the url
            keystroke (item i of urlList)
            key code 36
        end repeat
    end tell
end tell
```

**Can someone help me from here in?
The first thing I need is the delay function. So, before this script does anything it waits for 61 minutes.**

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Seems pretty straightforward. Can you share the code and let us know which part you are having trouble with?

Comment: I actually have nothing right now. I mean I have had success with AppleScript and opening Safari, but that's as far as my knowledge goes.